# Unable to set sort_in_tempdb

Tags: sql-server, database

1. I am using SQL Server 2014. While creating the index I am setting the `SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON` but it is not set. As per my search this doesn't have any other config. Can someone please help me how to debug this.
2. We have a index created on 4 columns. Sometimes we have to use a query which uses only 3 columns of this index. To get the performance we create another index with 3 columns. FYI, both the indexes are partitioned using fileName

Code:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_FileName] 
ON Table_1(columns)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, 
          DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [fileName_partitionscheme]([FileName])
```

Questions:

1. Is there a possibility of some optimization here in SQL Server 2014 since the 3 fields are common between both the indexes.
2. After creating the 2 indexes, the bulk copy is talking lot of time.. I can't disable the indexing while loading because we have producer and consumer modules separate..

Is there a way to disable the indexing on the partition?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say "it is not set" (in re: sort_in_tempdb, what does that mean? That only has relevance to the actual creation of the index and has no bearing on anything once the index is actually created.

As for the others, the wider index will be used as long as the seek predicate is a left-based subset of the index columns. So, if the index is on (A,B,C,D) and you seek on (A,B,C), the index will be considered.

And lastly, why not bulk load into an empty table and switch the partition in? It's one of the selling points of partitioning.

Comment: after the index is created with (sort_in_tempdb set to true).. I am looking at the properties of the index, in the property window sort_in_tempdb is set to false.. The 2nd index is created on (A,C,D) so I think the 1st index can't be used in this case? can you please describe more about the switch partition....

Comment: So that's the SSMS developers being lazy, er, reusing a dialog. That is, if you clickety-clack your way through creating an index through the GUI (as opposed to writing the DDL), that same dialog will be in play. Look in the sys.indexes table and you'll see that there's no place where the sort_in_tempdb option is stored, so there's no way that it would ever be "populated" for a live index.

Comment: I am creating the index on an empty table with sort_in_tempdb=true.. I tried creating the index with an sql command and also through GUI... In both cases, I am verifying where it is set or not using the table->index->property dialog box, but i am seeing it is not being set.. How can I debug this further?

Comment: You don't. What I've been saying all along is that sort_in_tempdb is not a property of an index, but rather an option that you can specify that says how the index is created. Once the index exists (i.e. the create index statement completes), whether or not sort_in_tempdb was specified at creation time isn't stored anywhere because it doesn't matter.

Comment: Then how do I know if the sort_in_tempdb option is set or not?

Comment: @BenThul https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/sort-in-tempdb-option-for-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know after the fact. Is not a property on the index. An analogy would be: let's say you're getting a package delivered and you have the ability to specify whether to use a bike courier or not. You tell the company to use the bike courier. The package is now sitting on your front step. How do you know that they used the bike courier? The answer is: you don't. But it doesn't matter as the result was accomplished (I.e. the package was delivered).